# Can it be possible to get a mutually orthogonal vector in this case?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality, gram-schmidt

Suppose $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ are real vectors of length $N>3$.

If we use Gram-Schmidt process, we can find two orthogonal vectors $\mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2$ such that
$$
\mathbf{u}_1 = \mathbf{v}_1\ ,
$$
$$
\mathbf{u}_2 = \mathbf{v}_2 - \frac{<\mathbf{v}_2,\mathbf{u}_1>}{<\mathbf{u}_1,\mathbf{u}_1>}\mathbf{u}_1\ ,
$$
where $<\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}>$ denotes the inner product between the two vectors $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}$.

But I am wondering whether it is possible to find a vector $\mathbf{z}$ that is mutually orthogonal to $\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2$.

Comment: You can choose basically any other vector $v_3$ and iterate the project and subtraction step used to obtain $u_2$.

Comment: @Laray Thanks for the comment. It works, indeed! It can be then any vector as long as it is orthogonal to $\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are dealing with vectors $\in \mathbb R^3$ we can use cross product to obtain

$$z=v_1 \times v_2$$

otherwise we can proceed again by G-S selecting any $v_3$ which is not in the span of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I understand correctly, I can set any random vector $\mathbf{v}_3$, then proceed again Gram-Schmidt process so that I can get $\mathbf{z}$.

Comment: yes of course exactly!